# How can I trigger events to fire on connected clients using node.js, sockets.io and redis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nosql, websocket, redis

Ok, so I previously asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251479/in-node-js-what-storage-technologies-are-available-for-real-time-games/8251656#8251656) asking about my options, I have looked into sockets.io and redis, and really like what I see.

Anyway, I would like to have multiple clients connected to a node.js server. Then when my redis db has a change, for example some boolean from 0 to 1, I want all node.js connections to send this update to all clients.

I am not looking for some code to loop and check for this change, I am wondering how I can fire an event to specific clients when a change is made in a redis db. Any psuedo code to help me get my mind around this, would be awesome. I would also really appreciate any node.js code that shows how to hook an event to changes in a redis instance.

Cheers, Josh

Comment: You accidentally the pseudocode.

Comment: -Sorry I hit enter, and posted before I had finished the question >< I realized I don't really know how the pseudo code would work. Because my understanding is limited to events only being fired when a client connects, messages and disconnects and not when the server separately does anything.

Comment: @jezternz listen on redis, when redis says data changed, broadcast that data to all clients on socket.io (these clients much listen on  that data event)

Comment: I hope this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8093261/694199) will solve your problem

Comment: oh yes! @GaneshKumar I psubscribe is the method i was particularly looking for. I also assume you can change the '*' to a more specific change in the database? this is scalable? (many clients can subscribe at the same time)?

Comment: yes you can use. But result is not better than my example

Comment: @GaneshKumar Is there some way I can say this question was answered, via a comment (not an answer) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't write any node.js code for you, but sounds like what you want is exactly what Redis's pub/sub functionality is for:

http://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Each node.js client would subscribe to a channel, where they will block/wait for messages to arrive. No looping/polling required.

Comment: My only real concern with using this method, is sociability? Would it be inefficient to have thousands of clients connected simultaneously all using this method? How about if each client had multiple subscriptions?